# Can Rocket Boots be found in Chests?

Tags: terraria

One of the few items I have yet to obtain in Terraria is a pair of rocket boots.

Common wisdom is that they drop from the goblin invasions that occur every so often. Scuttlebutt says they *also* spawn in chests on floating islands or in dungeons.

I have scoured [both](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Rocket_boots) [wikis](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Rocket_Boots), but the only mention of finding rocket boots in chests is in this youtube video:

Obviously, if rocket boots *can't* be found in chests I shouldn't waste my time finding floating islands or battling Skeletron, so I am looking for some independent confirmation that they are a possible chest item in the first place (Or at least some volume of proof more than a single mention in a single youtube video).

Comment: You can now buy them from the [Goblin Tinkerer](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Goblin_Tinkerer) (an NPC you can free underground after you defeat the Goblin Army once).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rocket Boots are not dropped by any mob on the game or found in any chests, they are sold by the goblin tinkerer NPC who is usually found in the underground jungle after the goblin invasion has been defeated at least once.

Answer (score 23):

No, the Rocket Boots cannot be found in any chests, nor do they drop from anything including shadow orbs, any enemies or bosses.

They can only be acquired by purchasing them from the Goblin Tinkerer for 5 gold.

Comment: In all cases, I think you mean "The following items can only be found in…" rather than "Only the following items can be found in…".

Comment: If it were to drop from chest, you would see much more reference to it. All I see is 1 or 2 messages in a sea of goblin invasions which just make a reference to something they haven't confirmed. @BenBlank: True, but I'm going to sleep now. Feel free to suggest an edit, I feel like adding links in the post tomorrow but that's quite time consuming given the amount of units so I might not be doing it. Anyway, I'm glad I figured this out as I was wondering if doing the Dungeon again would yield me with more interesting stuff, apparently not.

Comment: @Tom - I feel like you might want to add in the shadow orb drops, just for completeness :P

Comment: @Raven Dreamer — That way lies madness.  At least it's just chests, for now.  ;-)

Comment: This is wrong. I just got a Cloud in a Bottle from an island chest.

Comment: @Sergio: Incorrect, check [Terraria Online - Chest](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Chest).

Comment: @Tom: Regardless, I'm telling you I just found one. Regardless what official listing say. Might be a bug, might not, but I found one.

Comment: @Sergio: But was it inside an island house or just outside the house? Are you running the latest version? I've confirmed that this is not a bug; inside a house you are locked to an enumeration of the three items, outside a house you have the buried chests...

Comment: Just letting you know that some of your images were affected by [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95732/163265 "meta.so: Images manually uploaded to Imgur are not displaying?").

Comment: The contents of this question have been greatly reduced to fit the criteria for an answer. For further followups or inquiries, please refer to this [meta post for reference.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10940/what-should-we-do-about-existing-extra-long-list-answers/10942#10942)